# NET - WebView2 / Open URL

Tags: webview2

I am using WebView2 control to open some page. Question is: How to open url on loaded page?
I did this for WebBrowser1 as below but i have no idea to  for WebView2:

```
For Each link As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.Links
            If link.GetAttribute("href") = userLink Then                
                link.InvokeMember("click")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
```

Comment: Seems you already know the url (as `userLink`), simply set the `Source` property to that value.

Answer (score 1):

WebView2 does not expose the DOM objects via its API. If you want to interact with the elements in the document you'll need to do it via JavaScript that you inject with `CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync`. For example the following script:

```js
for (let link of document.links) {
    if (link.href === "https://example.com/") { 
        link.click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you may need to use CoreWebView2. Assuming, you have the URL as userLink, do this.

`<webView2 object>.CoreWebView2.Navigate(userLink);`

Comment: Dears, I know about navigate to url. My case is about click event on specific url without mouse.